# "Anaconda can not spawn a new process..." I have sublime text error

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, sublimetext3

OS: window 10
Tensorflow version: 2.0.0
python: 3.7

After I installed tensorflow = 2.0.0, the error has occurred. When I open sublime text3, the error message pops up. It says

**Anaconda.anaconda_lib.workers.local_process.LocalProcess object at Ox000001DE094E9DD8> process can not start a new anaconda JsonServer in the operating system because: Anaconda can not spawn a new process with your current configured python interpreter (python) Make sure your interpreter is a valid binary and is in your PATH or use an absolute path to it, for example: C:\Python27\python.exe**

Actually, It doesn't shoot any trouble, when I run some python coding with tensorflow, but it's annoying..,
Every time I open sublime text, the error message comes out. When I do on pycharm, there is no error like this, and it works perfectly in terms of running tensorflow and anaconda.

I tried delete and install sublime text, but nothing has changed. Please help me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change Anaconda.sublime-settings User to have the following line (along with any other settings your might have)

{
    "python_interpreter": "python3"
}

I had same issue, hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I haven't checked overflow...   So I followed by your answer, and I've got no error!! I went to Anaconda.sublime-settings User then I changed code "python_interpreter": "/usr/local/bin/python3" into "python_interpreter": "python3". It works fine as I try build the tensorflow code. Is this what you meant?